# Confusion related to multitarget regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have a bunch of features/xs and a bunch of targets ys. I want to run a linear regression on this. I don't know if I should take every y to be independent and learn separate regression models or just a single model with multitargets and xs. What would be the best?

If I have to do with multiple ys how can I do it?

Comment: how are the targets (y variables) related? Can you provide us with what these y variables are or a similar example of what these y variables are? Typically, your models will be much more explanatory and/or predictive if you individually build a model for each target variable

Comment: These ys are measurements at different locations

Answer (score 1):

I believe canocial correlation is a technique that can be used to approach this kind of problem. Canonical correlation is a general multivariate form that measures the strength of the relationship between two SETS of variables - one set of predictor variables and a set of response variables. The objective of canonical correlation is to find a simultaneous relationship between linear combinations of the original variables.

In R, see:

```
help(cancor)
```

I'll also note that I there are multivariate normality assumptions associated with the technique require testing. Structural Equation Modeling and GLM are also options. For an overview of canonical correlation, see:

[How to visualize what canonical correlation analysis does (in comparison to what principal component analysis does)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65692/how-to-visualize-what-canonical-correlation-analysis-does-in-comparison-to-what)