# Visualization of canonical correlation analysis results

Tags: r, data-visualization, canonical-correlation

What is a good way to visualize the results of canonical correlation analysis (CCA)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to visualize what canonical correlation analysis does (in comparison to what principal component analysis does)?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65692/how-to-visualize-what-canonical-correlation-analysis-does-in-comparison-to-what)

Comment: @Andy, that's for understanding what CCA itself is, this is for understanding your data & results.

Comment: @gung right, thanks for the clarification. I retracted the close vote.

Comment: On doing CCA we get a set of transformations which basically tells us the directions in which the data are maximally correlated. We can project the data into the first two directions and display them. Now compare the original data distribution in its first two dimensions.

Comment: http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v33/rasiwasia14.html -- kindly please check this paper they have good visualization examples.