# What is the difference between a PCA, RDA and CCA analysis?

Tags: pca, ordinal-data, canonical-correlation, redundancy-analysis, hellinger

I am trying to understand the difference between a PCA, RDA and CCA analysis. Here is an example of a CCA triplot. It seems that a PCA + RDA = CCA plot. Here it's a CCA triplot, which incorporates one other component.

[image]

Comment: PCA and CCA are quite different. One answer is here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/65692/3277. Also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/231815/3277