# is there a geometric interpretation of canoncial correlation analysis?

Tags: correlation, canonical-correlation

I am looking for a geometric interpretation of CCA. Especially one that relies on the fact we are doing singular value decomposition, which has the geometric interpretation of a rotation, scaling and another rotation. Why taking these two rotations from the SVD of the cross-correlation matrix gives the most correlated linear projections?

Comment: Can this help? http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/65692/3277