# Visualizing the difference between uncorrelatedness and orthogonality

Tags: correlation, intuition, centering, geometry

A previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12128/what-does-orthogonal-mean-in-the-context-of-statistics) received a [linked answer](http://www.psych.umn.edu/faculty/waller/classes/FA2010/Readings/rodgers.pdf) as below:

> The first important distinction here is that linear independence
>   and orthogonality are properties of the raw  variables, while zero
>   correlation is a property of the  centered variables

and

> The key to appreciating this distinction is recognizing that 
>   centering each variable can and often will change the angle between
>   the two vectors.

I'm having a hard time visualizing what "centering a variable" means and how it may change the angle. Could anyone produce an image?

Comment: I think the distinction is pretty clear. Orthogonality means $X'X=0$, while uncorrelated means $(X-\bar{X})'(X-\bar{X})=0$.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood where your difficulty lies.

Comment: +1, this is a good question. Unfortunately, I think the necessary picture would need to be in a high-dimensional space. In other words, I'm not sure how well it can be pictured.

Comment: If it's just 2 variables $X$ and $Y$, shouldn't the picture simply be in $R^2$?

Comment: I may recommend you visualization in the [subject space](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51471/3277). Pearson r between two vectors _is_ the [cosine](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36158/3277) between them when the vectors are centered. Centering is bringing the mean to 0. Centered vector (variable) X is $X_i-\mu$.